# How to create a remote virtual machine client for iPhone? (in XCode)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, virtual-machine

I desperately need to integrate a virtual machine/remote desktop connection into my iOS app because the app is going to be developed for a school and they want to access the school management system.

Is it very hard? How can I do it? Are there any tutorials out there?

Bear in mind that I'm not an advanced dev.

Many thanks,

James

Comment: Apple will not accept any app that does this on the App Store. Be warned.

Comment: There are over 2 dozen remote desktop type apps that Apple has accepted into the app store.  As long as the VM is remote, it's OK.

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan - The original question was poorly worded, but Apple does accept apps with embedded VMs as long as they cannot download any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most mobile apps use a [RESTful API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) to communicate between servers and devices.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely to be a challenge.
A better way would be trying to use a web service to interact with the system.

Comment: Which sort of web service? How did the guys at LogMeIn do it? :)

Comment: The idea behind using a web service would be to avoid accessing another computer to manage the system, but what kind of service you used would be dependent on the system they were running. Creating an app to manage a specific system, and including remote access functionality would be pointless, and you might as well just get them to buy logmein, or TeamViewer (free). - However using a web service to directly interact with it, would be efficient, quick, and  could be formatted nicely to an iPhone screen.

Comment: Companies like logmein implement a remote desk, VNC or similar protocol.  It's very hard, and usually requires a team of experienced programmers, or the porting of existing open source RDesktop or VNC code.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard.  Look into porting some open source RDesktop code.  Or just use one of the dozens of existing remote desktop iPhone apps in conjunction with your app.